# What is distribution of lengths of gaps between occurrences of ones in Bernoulli process?

Tags: distributions, unbiased-estimator, bernoulli-distribution, geometric-distribution

Which distribution fits the following data? Data are generated by the process:

$X_t, \, t=\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ is equal 1 with probability $p$, and 0 with probability $(1-p)$ for each $t$.

What is the distribution of gaps between each occurrence of 1?

Example series: $0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1$ gives gaps $2,0,1,1,1,3$.

How to fit that distribution if I don't know $p$? $p$ is going to be the only free parameter of that distribution, so is $\hat p = \frac{n_1}{n}$, where $n_1$ is the number of ones in the series an unbiased estimator of the free parameter in that distribution ?

Answer (score 8):

The time you have to wait till the next one is a geometric variable $X\sim\mathcal{G}(p)$ with probability parameter $p$, i.e.
$$
\mathbb{P}(X=k) = (1-p)^k p \quad k=0,1,2,\ldots
$$

Fitting your distribution to the data presumably means estimating $p$ by $\hat p$ and using the pluggin distribution $\mathcal{G}(\hat p)$ for all purposes. If you do not want to run a Bayesian analysis (with prior $\pi(p)=1/\sqrt{p(1-p)}$), estimating $p$ from your proportion of $1$'s along the Bernoulli sequence is indeed an unbiased estimator.

Comment: (+1) Indeed, the unbiased estimator you describe is the minimum variance unbiased estimator. :)

Comment: what is the source of that prior distribution used in Bayesian analysis ?

Comment: @Obik: This is the reference or default prior used for parameters on $(0,1)$. See, e.g., [The Bayesian Choice](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0387715983?ie=UTF8&tag=chrprobboo-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0387715983), Chap. 3.